# How can I call the value from a Jtoken

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I have a JSON object, then I loop through all the Children and add the items to a list of JTokens. When I debug, the list contains the following :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXZDI.jpg

When I show a MessageBox I get the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUuji.jpg

The problem is, I just want the string text as: 'Volunteer'. How can I do it?

```
List<JToken> objecten = new List<JToken>();

JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
foreach (JToken token in json.Children<JToken>())
{
   objecten.Add(token);
}

MessageBox.Show(objecten[1].ToString());
```

If I want to get the role in a string variable, I would like to do it like this but I don't know how it works:

string role = objecten.Role;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SelectToken` wherein you can select your desire value base on their path. See this [reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm).

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);    
var value = json.SelectToken("role").Value<string>();
```

Add a path to select `role`. The path will depend on your JSON structure.

Example value of content

```
{
   response : {
       role : volunteer,
       success: true,
       token: eyJhbGci...
   }
}

JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);    
var value = json.SelectToken("response.role").Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> sourcePair in json)
           {
               if (sourcePair.Key == "Role")
                    role = sourcePair.Value.ToString();
            }
```

With recursion you can pass through all json object without know the complete path of the attributes